# How to plot a 3d surface in Python, with all values from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph, pycharm

I was trying to plot a 3D scatter -- surface plot using Python with below data(it only allow me to attach picture):
[image]

and I would like to draw a 3D surface like using excel(doesn't have to be grid/mesh, solid surface is fine):
[image]

However I searched multiple documents and tutors and found it's fairly difficult to do plot because it seems like Matplotlib is either using z=f(x,y) function to plot, or using 3 lists x,y,z = [],[],[], Could someone help to give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: `x,y = np.meshgrid(df.index, df.columns)` and plot with `x,y, df.values`?

Comment: I think df.values is a 2D array. For all data passes to matplotlib, it ran np.isnan() to the data first, and np.isnan() reported error: "ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"